# How to get value of appended input div on appended button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple HTML like this;

```
<div id="buildyourform">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
        
        <select class="form-control" id="language">
        @foreach($language as $l)
            <option value="{{$l->id}}" >{{$l->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="save-button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm ">
        <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
        Upload
    </a>
   
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have a plus button, using which I am appending the same fields below. Now I want to retrieve the respective selected language id with the click of the respective upload button.
But every time it returns me the value of first select field.

Here is what I have tried;

```
 $(document).on('click', '#save-button', function(){

    var obj=$(this);
    //language = obj.closest("div[class=row]").find("select[id=language]").val();
    language = $(this).parent().find("select[id=language]").val();
    console.log(language);

 });
```

Can anyone let me know how to get respective selected language id on respective button click?

Comment: Just tested and its work for me. Are you sure all the `$l->id` are unique?

Comment: Yes it is unique

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky it doesnot get value for the appended div. Is my way correct?

Comment: Try to pass language id in quote like .find("select[id='language']").val();

Comment: Do you clone ``save-button`` too on ``plus-button`` click? If so, the you should use id instead of ``save-button`` id?

Comment: Hello, did you saw my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use prev function and change select[id=xxxx] by select#language

https://api.jquery.com/prev/

```js
$(document).on('click', '#save-button', function(){
  var obj=$(this);
  //language = obj.closest("div[class=row]").find("select[id=language]").val();
  language = $(this).prev('.col-sm-6').find("select#language").val();
  console.log(language);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buildyourform">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
        
        <select class="form-control" id="language">
        @foreach($language as $l)
            <option value="{{$l->id}}" >{{$l->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="save-button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm ">
        <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
        Upload
    </a>
   
    </div>
</div>
```